# Next js 13 metadata not statically generating

Tags: reactjs, next.js, metadata, meta-tags, next-auth

I am trying to use the new [metadata api](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/metadata). It shows up in the `<head>` like so:
[image: meta-html-code-example]

My app is currently deployed at https://flower-shop-three.vercel.app/

But when actually testing it on https://metatags.io/ and other meta tag testers it doesn't work. I tried testing it on twitter and that also don't work. I think the reason is that the metatags don't get generated statically but rather added after the website loads. I have no clue how to fix it.

The full project is up on GitHub: https://github.com/FarouqJalabi/Flower-shop
Here is where I implement the meta tags

The tutorials I saw didn't use [next-auth](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-auth).

Could that be the issue?

#### layout.tsx

```
import "./globals.css";
import { Inter, Jua } from "next/font/google";

import Nav from "../components/nav";
import Footer from "../components/footer";

import { NextAuthProvider } from "./contexts/authProvider";

import { Metadata } from "next";

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Flower Shop",
  description: "A mock flower shop",
  metadataBase: new URL("https://flower-shop-three.vercel.app/"),
  openGraph: {
    type: "website",
    url: "https://flower-shop-three.vercel.app/",
    title: "Flower Shop",
    description: "A mock flower shop",
    siteName: "Flower shop",
    // images: [
    //   {
    //     url: "https://example.com/og.png",
    //   },
    // ],
  },

  other: {
    "google-site-verification": SECRET,
  },
};

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });
const jua = Jua({
  subsets: ["latin"],
  weight: "400",
  variable: "--font-jua",
  preload: true,
});

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={`${inter.className} ${jua.variable} overflow-x-hidden`}>
        <NextAuthProvider>
          <Nav />
          {children}
        </NextAuthProvider>
        <Footer />
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

I expected that the tags will show up in twitter, metatags.io and other meta tags testing websites.